# How to read multiple xlsx file in R using loop with specific rows and columns

Tags: r, excel, loops, dataframe, xlsx

I have to read multiple xlsx file with random names into single dataframe. Structure of each file is same. I have to import specific columns only.

I tried this:

```
dat <- read.xlsx("FILE.xlsx", sheetIndex=1, 
                  sheetName=NULL, startRow=5, 
                  endRow=NULL, as.data.frame=TRUE, 
                  header=TRUE)
```

But this is for only one file at a time and I couldn't specify my particular columns.
I even tried :

```
site=list.files(pattern='[.]xls')
```

but after that loop isn't working. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would read each sheet to a list:

Get file names:

```
f = list.files("./")
```

Read files:

```
dat = lapply(f, function(i){
    x = read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex=1, sheetName=NULL, startRow=5,
        endRow=NULL, as.data.frame=TRUE, header=T)
    # Get the columns you want, e.g. 1, 3, 5
    x = x[, c(1, 3, 5)]
    # You may want to add a column to say which file they're from
    x$file = i
    # Return your data
    x
})
```

You can then access the items in your list with:

```
dat[[1]]
```

Or do the same task to them with:

```
lapply(dat, colmeans)
```

Turn them into a data frame (where your file column now becomes useful):

```
dat = do.call("rbind.data.frame", dat)
```

Comment: Hey your code did work for me but it worked only for very small size files say 50KB. But I have files which are around 1MB size. What should I do then?

Comment: Try a different excel reading package, this one may be your best bet: http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/15/readxl-0-1-0/. Also note that opening many files at the same time is likely to cause you memory problems.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but getting 0 obs in the final dataframe                
```path = "/K_Data/"
l = list.files(path = path, "xlsx")                                                                                    all = lapply(l, function(x){
sup = read_excel(i, sheet="Sup", skip = 2)
ID =  read_excel(x, sheet="Mea",  col_names = FALSE)
id =  as.character( ID[1,1])
mass = as.numeric(ID[3,5])                                                                                    
sup= sup%>%
mutate(ID = id, Mass = mass)  })
dat = do.call("rbind.data.frame", all) ```

Comment: you need to print/return your data at the end of the lapply function. e.g.:
    ...
      sup= sup%>% mutate(ID = id, Mass = mass)
      sup})
    dat = do.call("rbind.data.frame", all)

Answer (score 1):

I am more familiar with a for loop, which can be a bit more cumbersome.

`filelist <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx")` # list all the xlsx files from the directory

```
allxlsx.files <- list()  # create a list to populate with xlsx data (if you wind to bind all the rows together)
count <- 1
for (file in filelist) {
   dat <- read.xlsx(file, sheetIndex=1, 
              sheetName=NULL, startRow=5, 
              endRow=NULL, as.data.frame=TRUE, 
              header=TRUE) [c(5:10, 12,15)] # index your columns of interest
   allxlsx.files[[count]] <-dat # creat a list of rows from xls files
   count <- count + 1
}
```

convert back to data.frame

```
allfiles <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, allxlsx.files)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a variation on Wyldsoul's answer, but using a for loop across multiple Excel sheets (between 1 and j) in the same Excel file, and binding with dplyr:

```
library(gdata) 
library(dplyr)

for (i in 1:j) {
  dat <- read.xls(f, sheet = i) 
  dat <- dat[,1:14] # index your columns of interest
  allxlsx.files[[count]]
  count <- count + 1
}

allfiles <- do.call(bind_rows, allxlsx.files)
```

Comment: You need to assign something to `allxlsx.files[[count]]`, probably `dat`, and you can simplify your last line to `bind_rows(allxlsx.files)`