# Read multiple xlsx files with multiple sheets into one R data frame - set_names function issue

Tags: r

I would like to read in multiple xlsx files into R that have multiple sheets, I have a header (colnames) for the first sheet of each file but I don't have any for the rest of the sheets, however, it's the exact same columns.

I found that solution in a post:

```r
dir_path <- "~/test_dir/"         # target directory path where the xlsx files are located. 
re_file <- "^test[0-9]\\.xlsx"    # regex pattern to match the file name format, in this case 'test1.xlsx', 'test2.xlsx' etc, but could simply be 'xlsx'.

read_sheets <- function(dir_path, file){
  xlsx_file <- paste0(dir_path, file)
  xlsx_file %>%
    excel_sheets() %>%
    set_names() %>%
    map_df(read_excel, path = xlsx_file, .id = 'sheet_name') %>% 
    mutate(file_name = file) %>% 
    select(file_name, sheet_name, everything())
}

df <- list.files(dir_path, re_file) %>% 
  map_df(~ read_sheets(dir_path, .))
```

but I can't figure out why it won't work, I get this error.

> ```
> Error in set_names(.) : 1 argument passed to 'names<-' which requires 2
> ```

Comment: set_names() needs the vector to be named and a vector with the names. In the block of code set_names() is passed the vector to be named, but not the vector of names to be given to it. Try excel_sheets() %>% unlist() %>%
    set_names() %>%

Comment: Where did you find this example? What exactly are you trying to do with set_names?

Comment: i got in a response to this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197705/read-multiple-xlsx-files-with-multiple-sheets-into-one-r-data-frame), I don't know what set_names is for

Comment: @PabloRod it gives the same error when adding unlist, i tried without the set_names instruction and it gives me that error:  Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default

Comment: Sorry, try removing set_names() %>%

Comment: @PabloRod i did and it gave me another error message: ` Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`

Comment: if you have antother way so that i can read all the sheet of my xlsx files,  and bind them all together, i am all ears

Comment: Do all the sheets have the exact same columns and rows?

Comment: Yes @Sven, I have a header ( colnames) for the first sheet of each file but i don't have any for the rest of the sheets

Comment: @Kaina, that might explain your issue and is important information to add in your question. Please add what your files and sheets look like.

Comment: @Sven it's done

Comment: Waht about purrr::set_names() instead of set_names() ?

Comment: Many thanks for that question! Just solved a big problem that I had! :-) As I wanted all the xlsx files in the same path, I just used: ' re_file <- ".xlsx" ' and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've created this `readxl` solution with 2 excel workbooks, each having 2 sheets with the same columns. In your problem the 2nd sheet (and further) doesn't have the `colnames`, so they needed to be set with an additional `if` statement. It's probably not the fastest solution, but it works:

```
library(readxl)    

#Set path
inputFolder <- "test/"

#Get list of files
fileList <- list.files(path = inputFolder, recursive=T, pattern='*.xlsx')

#Read in each sheet from each excel
for (f in 1:length(fileList)){
  #Find the number of sheets in this workbook
  sheetList <- excel_sheets(paste(inputFolder, fileList[f], sep = ""))
  #Get the sheets of this workbook
  for (s in 1:length(sheetList)) {
    tempSheet <- read_excel(paste(inputFolder, fileList[f], sep = ""), sheet = sheetList[s])
    if (f == 1 & s == 1) {
      df <- tempSheet
    }
    else {
      if(s != 1) {
        names(tempSheet) <- names(df)
      }
      df <- rbind(df,tempSheet)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kaina, you're very welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you. 

Comment: after using the code to read multiple files with multiple sheet, I realized that it dosen't read correctly the files, it puts NA's where it shouln't, can you please help me on this ? or anyone else ?

Comment: Is there anything specific about the files or sheets where it doesn't read them correctly? Are you saying it doesn't read the files at all, or puts NA's in some cells that shouldn't be NA's?

Comment: it does read the files, but it has errors in it, there is NA's values in some cells where it souldn't be

Comment: Then it's probably better to raise a new question for that.

Comment: ook @Sven, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

That seems to work.  Here is a different means to the same end.

```
library(XLConnect)

testDir <- "C:\\your_path_here\\"

re_file <- ".+\\.xls.?"
testFiles <- list.files(testDir, re_file, full.names = TRUE)

# This function rbinds in a single dataframe
# the content of multiple sheets in the same workbook
# (assuming that all the sheets have the same column types)
rbindAllSheets <- function(file) {
  wb <- loadWorkbook(file)
  sheets <- getSheets(wb)
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(sheets, function(sheet) {
            readWorksheet(wb, sheet)
          })
  )
}

# Getting a single dataframe for all the Excel files
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(testFiles, rbindAllSheets))
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i tried it and it gave me this error   ` Error: POIXMLException (Java): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`